# iPhone 3GS not working with any docks, ideas?

Tags: iphone, dock

About a month ago, my iPhone 3GS just stopped working with docks in terms of playing music. It can still charge via docks and I can still connect it to my computer and iTunes for syncing, but it just will not play music through the dock connector.
I have upgraded to an iPhone 5, which is why I have not gotten around to try and fix this issue yet, but I would like to see if there is a solution as I would like to enjoy using my 3GS as a permanent iPod for my car (via the car's dock connector obviously).

I have tried cleaning the port on the phone with a slightly wet cloth and toothpick, and also some alcohol, but no luck. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: What happens if you play music in the dock? Does the phone simply plays music with his own speakers? Or do you hear nothing at all?

Comment: Do you have another 3GS to try? I found that my old 3GS, once updated to a certain IPSW, would no longer play with many accessories. I would be interested to know if another device running another OS level will work.